# Proving that revealed preference relation is the only relation that is rational and rationalizes the choice structure

Tags: solution-verification, economics

> The revealed preference relation is the only preference relation that is rational and rationalizes the choice structure that it was revealed from. It is unique.

How do I go about proving this? I thought of this but I have no Idea how to give a concrete proof. I just have an example using a decision from a set of 3:

$B: \{X, Y, Z\}\ C(B) = X$. Then the revealed preference relation we can derive from this choice structure is: $X >\geq Y$, $X \geq Z$. From this revealed preference relation, the only choice structure that we can derive from it is $\{X, Y, Z\}\ C(B) = X$.